# Use sass variable and mixins from base theme in sub theme

Tags: theming

I need some help regarding sub theming with sass. The sub theme setup is as follows :

1. There is a base theme `base` which has sass variables and mixins defined.
2. I run grunt and compile the sass.
3. There is a subtheme of `base` called `microsite` with similar sass structure as `base` but no styles as presently it uses only the base styles.

Q. How do I use the sass variables and mixins defined in `base` theme inside `microsite` theme?

Eg - 1 : Inheriting the base color palette.

I have a color palette defined under base theme with my color variables. `themes/custom/base/sass/core/variables/_palette.scss`

I want to use these palette variables in defining styles in my `microsite` subtheme at `themes/custom/microsite/sass/base/color/_buttons.scss`.

Eg - 2 : Inheriting the base gradient mixin.

I have a linear-gradient mixin defined under base theme at `themes/custom/base/sass/core/abstractions/_linear-gradient.scss`

I want to use this mixin in defining styles in my `microsite` subtheme at `themes/custom/microsite/sass/base/color/_buttons.scss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special process because it's Drupal or sub/parent theme relationships, just import what you need. E.g.

```
@import '../../../../base/sass/core/abstractions/_linear-gradient.scss';
```